# How to use oslo_message as the client Load Balancer of RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq cluster of 3 nodes

```
root@47704165d2bb:/# rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@47704165d2bb ...
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@0482398a286e,rabbit@3709521b608a,
            rabbit@47704165d2bb]}]},
 {running_nodes,    [rabbit@0482398a286e,rabbit@3709521b608a,rabbit@47704165d2bb]},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@47704165d2bb">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{rabbit@0482398a286e,[]},
          {rabbit@3709521b608a,[]},
          {rabbit@47704165d2bb,[]}]}]
root@47704165d2bb:/# rabbitmqctl list_policies      
Listing policies ...
/       ha-all  all     ^ha\\.  {"ha-mode":"all"}       0
```

My oslo_message client configuration

```
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_hosts=120.0.0.56:5671,120.0.0.57:5671,120.0.0.55:5671
rabbit_userid=cloud
rabbit_password=cloud
rabbit_ha_queues=True
rabbit_retry_interval=1
rabbit_retry_backoff=2
rabbit_max_retries=0
rabbit_durable_queues=False
```

When I run "service rabbitmq-server stop" on one node to simulating a failure, I got following error logs, and the consumer can't failover from the bad node. It will reconnect the failure node forever instead of other nodes. "kombu_failover_strategy" is default value of "round-robin".

```
2009-01-13 18:32:42.785 17 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] [4e976d46-ceee-4617-b9be-5e4821990738] AMQP server 120.0.0.56:5671 closed the connection. Check login credentials: Socket closed
2009-01-13 18:32:43.819 17 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Unable to connect to AMQP server on 120.0.0.56:5671 after None tries: Socket closed
2009-01-13 18:32:43.819 17 WARNING oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Unexpected error during heartbeart thread processing, retrying...
2009-01-13 18:32:58.874 17 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] [4e976d46-ceee-4617-b9be-5e4821990738] AMQP server 120.0.0.56:5671 closed the connection. Check login credentials: Socket closed
2009-01-13 18:32:59.907 17 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Unable to connect to AMQP server on 120.0.0.56:5671 after None tries: Socket closed
2009-01-13 18:32:59.907 17 WARNING oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Unexpected error during heartbeart thread processing, retrying...
```

Can someone help me? Thanks